# Буферизация вывода

Tags: php

Делаем

ob_start();
...
...
...

Как присвоить содержимое буфера переменной (для последующей записи в файл) и завершить буферизацию без вывода на экран?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ob_start(); //стартуем

echo 'some'; //код

$content = ob_get_contents(); // записываем в переменную

//действуем с $content

ob_end_clean(); // очищаем
```

Comment: [`ob_get_clean()`](http://php.net/ob-get-clean) - Get current buffer contents and delete current output buffer